# Scrolling to the top without triggering scroll()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am binding scroll to an element with some logic

```
$(".elem").scroll(function(){
 some logic
});
```

and it other places of the code I need to scroll to the top of the element, but without triggering the scroll event

```
$(".elem").scrollTop(0)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949234/jquery-scroll-without-triggering-on-scroll/50308631#50308631

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQuery scroll without triggering on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949234/jquery-scroll-without-triggering-on-scroll)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var disable_scroll = false;
    $(window).scroll(function(event) {
        if(disable_scroll == false){
            //your scroll code goes here..
        }
    });
    $("#button-id").on('click',function(){
        disable_scroll = true;
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top + 1
        }, function(){
            disable_scroll = false;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: is there a way to do this if they are in different files, without global variables?

Comment: I think you can check out [$.bind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) and [$.unbind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).. But if you load those jQuery in one HTML file then it shouldn't be a problem.. because the other file will recognize the `disable_scroll`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to temporary replace `scroll` event subscription.

```
// initial subscribe to scroll event
this.$el.on("scroll", this.handleScroll);

// unsubscribe initial handler and subscribe fake handler before manual scroll
this.$el.off("scroll");
this.$el.on("scroll", () =>
{
    this.$el.off("scroll");
    this.$el.on("scroll", this.handleScroll);
});

// scroll manually
this.$el.scrollTop(0);
```

However, if scroll event doesn't happen during manual scroll (during `this.$el.scrollTop(0);`), then handler will not be called on first scroll event. In this case, during first event, fake event will be unsubscribed, and original one re-subscribed, but will not called.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it by temporary remove the event, then add the same function after you called it. But I have another algorithm. I can't say it is a better or the best algorithm, but you can use it if you like it. :)

the "you called scrollTo" text will not printed and the event won't be triggered if you do scrollTo to the same position/coordinate. So, click the buttons in example below alternately to keep print the text.
It is occured because you tried to scroll to the same position, in javascript, it will be assumed as "not scrolling at all", so the event won't be triggered.

```js
  window.dontTrigger=0;/*
  If more than 0, then the body->onscroll is allowed to be triggered, else, it won't be triggered
  */
  window.scrollTo2=window.scrollTo;
  window.scrollTo=function(x,y){
  x=Math.ceil(x);
  y=Math.ceil(y); 
  var scrlX=Math.ceil(window.scrollX);
  var scrlY=Math.ceil(window.scrollY);
  if (!(x==(scrlX)) || !(y==(scrlY))) window.dontTrigger++;
  console.log(window.dontTrigger);
  window.scrollTo2(x,y);
  }
   function OnBodyScrollFunc(){
   //console.log(!window.dontTrigger);
    if (window.dontTrigger) {
    //If dontTrigger not 0, then skip
    window.dontTrigger--;
    console.log("you called scrollTo");
    return ;
    }else{
    console.log("You scrolled the page");
    }
  }
```

```html
<html>
 <body onscroll="OnBodyScrollFunc();">
<button type="button" onclick="window.scrollTo(0,50);" style="left:0px;position:fixed;">Scroll to (0,50)</button>
<button type="button" onclick="window.scrollTo(0,150);" style="right:0px;position:fixed;">Scroll to (0,150)</button>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
 </body>
</html>
```